# gdb: get gdb into foreground

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm using **gdb** to debug a program via a ssh session. After a while, the ssh session closed, and I can find it using **ps** command after I establish a new one. Is there any way that I can bring it back to foreground? The environment is **Linux Redhat**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The proper way to do this would be to use a program like `screen` or `tmux` to start the `gdb` session. This way, you can re-connect to your `screen`/`tmux` session even if your SSH session dies.

Comment: Thanks！ This works for me.